# Any chance to get view count on public CV?

Tags: discussion, developer-story

Is there a way to get a view count on my public CV via Stack Overflow?  Would be nice to get this information simply as some stat info directly on the CV?  Could be private to the author of the CV if security is some sort of concern.

Comment: with the same logic as view count on Questions? That records view counts for unique IP-addresses where IP-addresses are kept for 15 minutes (so you can increase your question viewcount 4 times in 60 minutes all by your self)

Comment: @rene - Yes and that's ok I know it wouldn't be perfect.  Most views are one click resume clicks to see what you are all about.  No one (unless you are really bored) will go back 4 times in 15 minute increments to get a view count up.  And if they do big deal I have 4 views by me..or someone.